# How set Element.HeightRequest from ios_observer?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I implement **ListViewRenderer** and try set **ContentSize.Height** to **Element.HeightRequest**  in **Observer**, but I got error "*got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.*"

```
public class DragAndDropListViewRenderer: ListViewRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ListView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        Control.Source = new ListViewDataSourceWrapper(Control.Source);
        Control.SetEditing(true, true);
        Control.ScrollEnabled = false;

        Control.AddObserver("contentSize", NSKeyValueObservingOptions.OldNew, change =>
                                                                   {
                                                                       var height = Control.ContentSize.Height;
                                                                       Element.HeightRequest = height;
                                                                   });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was easy.
Xamarin Native size and Xamarin Forms size is different. And in this case, I got a loop.

```
var height = Control.ContentSize.Height;                                        
Element.HeightRequest = height;
```

Control.ContentSize.Height is bigger then Element.HeightRequest, then all recalculate and observer work again. And then boom... and fatal error